# Dataframe drop rows that does not contain specific values in the column, result in empty df

Tags: pandas

I want to drop rows in `housing_plot_end` that does not contain one of 5 values specified in `plot_test_data['housing price median']` dataframe object.

'Dł. geograficzna' is the name of column and it translates to 'latitiude' in english but I left it as it was because maybe the space between these two words is causing a problem?

But I am receiving empty df with:

```
values_to_save = [plot_test_data['Dł. geograficzna']]
housing_plot_end=housing_plot_end[~housing_plot_end['Dł. geograficzna'].isin(values_to_save) 
== False]
enter code here
```

The column in `plot_test_data` contains of 5 numerical values thus 5 rows:

```
-121.46
-117.23
-119.04
-117.13
-118.7
```

Meanwhile housing_plot_end has tens of thousands of rows and I need to drop every row which does not contain one of these specific values in the column of `housing_plot_end['Dł. geograficzna']`

But I am receiving empty dataframe object when I've runned this code:

```
values_to_save = [plot_test_data['Dł. geograficzna']]
housing_plot_end=housing_plot_end[~housing_plot_end['Dł. geograficzna'].isin(values_to_save) 
== False]
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: I think you just need: `housing_plot_end[~housing_plot_end['Dł. geograficzna'].isin(plot_test_data['Dł. geograficzna'])`

Comment: @MuhammadHassan okay it worked.
But it turned out that I need to filter through more than one column to be left with 5 rows in 'housing_plot_end'.
I've tried implementing the line you wrote a couple of times for each column except for one in both dataframes but I was left just with 70% of initial count of rows in 'housing_plot_end'.
So what I'd need to write is a code that "compares" corresponding columns and deletes rows where at least one cell has different value.
I've tried smth like this 'df1[~df1['A']['B']].isin(df2['A']['B']), but it didn't worked

Comment: May be you need this: `housing_plot_end[~((housing_plot_end['Dł. geograficzna'].isin(plot_test_data['col_1'])) | (housing_plot_end['Dł. geograficzna'].isin(plot_test_data['col_2'])))]
`